# Problems not suitable for machine learning

Tags: machine-learning

I know there is a lot of problem suitable for machine learning, but what about the problem that are not suitable for it?

When we should not use machine learning?

Comment: stackoverflow probably isn't the best place for this question, since it is so broad. Do you have any applications in mind that you are struggling to formulate? If you have a specific problem you are trying to solve, then we can help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Too broad question for SO, but i'll try to answer theoretically:
The only problem in ML is a good generalization on unseen data, that has some pattern, because you can get some info (predict label, cluster) about new unseen data only if you learned something about distribution before. Theoretically you can force machine to learn any task that has non-random distribution relative to available features, but you need to have enough data for desired accuracy. That's why it's sometimes impossible in practice. Because to capture hard distribution rules you need to have big variative (more universal), or more specific (but it's includes your own knowledge about data) model, and to learn this model without overfitting you need to have big dataset, for all of this you need to have powerful computational resources and so on.

If you are interested in a more detailed explanation about theoretical aspect, you can watch lectures from caltech, starting from this [CaltechX - CS1156x Learning from data](https://youtu.be/MEG35RDD7RA?list=PLCA2C1469EA777F9A).

Also there are theoretical equations to predict generalization abilities of model with respect to available amount of data: [Vapnik–Chervonenkis theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapnik%E2%80%93Chervonenkis_theory)
[Akaike_information_criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion)